# Error message: Array bound is not an integer conctant before ';' token

Tags: c++11

```
void setup()
{
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
```

I have this as part of a program but it highlights

```
pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
```

and gives me the error message: Array bound is not an integer constant before ';' token.

Comment: Check your syntax. You have "[" instead of "(" in the rest of your lines.

Comment: please, include output of program as well as more than just these lines. For all we know it could be before this snippet

Comment: It depends on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Whereis  this pinMode function? Please show it

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume its the fact that this:

```
void setup()

[

pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
pinMode[6, OUTPUT);
pinMode[8, OUTPUT);
pinMode[9, OUTPUT);
pinMode[10, OUTPUT);
pinMode[11, OUTPUT);
pinMode[13, OUTPUT);
```

Should be this:

```
void setup()
{


   pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}
```